# Docker mounting file into container clears directory

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have a container that already contains files in a structure like this:

```
/var/www/html/pages/index.php
/var/www/html/pages/page1.php
/var/www/html/pages/page2.php
...
```

Now I have a page5.php which I want to mount into that container.

So my idea was:

```
server:
  image: myapp
volumes:
   - ./pages/page5.php:/var/www/html/pages/page5.php
   - ./pages/page6.php:/var/www/html/pages/page6.php
```

Which mounted the file in place.
Problem now is that all other files in this directory are gone and only page5.php and page6.php are placed in.

I there a way to mount that external files and keep the existing files in this directory?

Comment: Did you create the `myapp` Docker image? If so, what does the Dockerfile look like?

Comment: No it's created by 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

Its the typical behavior when you mount volumes.

The best would be bring all pages to `./pages/` and the mount to the container

```
|_pages/
    |_ page1.php
    |_ page2.php
    |_ ...
    |_ page5.php
    |_ page6.php
```

In `docker-compose` file

```
server:
  image: myapp
volumes:
   - ./pages/:/var/www/html/pages/
```

Comment: Typically I would do it that way. But the container is created and maintained by 3rd party. That would mean a lot of work on every update.

Comment: @Steve Are these 3rd party pages static or dynamic? If they are static, you can copy them to your local and then use mount option.